# What does __throw_bad_alloc() do?

Tags: c++

I came across this using the static analyzer in Xcode and couldn't find any documentation describing exactly what this function does. I've dome some Google searching without much luck. I've only found references to this function in some open source projects.

Comment: Sounds like an internal clang function that probably throws `bad_alloc`. That way you can delegate all your throws to functions, so if you disable exceptions you can handle it in the function.

Comment: In C and C++, any identifier beginning with 2 underscores - or any beginning with 1 underscore + a capital letter, or any in the global namespace beginning with 1 underscore - is reserved for use as an implementation (compiler, library, makefile, etc) detail. End-users shouldn't define such names, call predefined ones, or really worry about them at all.

Comment: Usually, it's a macro that defines bad allocation exception throwing routine. As you've probably already seen in those open source projects, it either uses std::bad_alloc() or does plain output in case first option is unavailable for some reason

Comment: The reason I ask, is that the static analyzer seemed to think a block of code was going to return nil and this was a step in the path. The analyzer seemed to think that the function would return and execution would continue. Whereas, as suggested, I would have expected the function to throw. The static analyzer could be wrong in this case, but I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: @underscore_d -- names that **contain** two underscores are reserved, not just names that **begin with** two underscores.

Comment: @PeteBecker Important correction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an internal artefact of the implementation, that you as a user don't need to know about.

We know it's internal, as it uses a reserved identifier (names containing consecutive underscores are all reserved), and we might guess from the name that it probably just throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

It may be more complex than simply throwing an exception in the normal way, as it has to function without making any allocations of its own.  It may also have configurable behaviour for use in non-default environments (e.g. where exceptions are disabled).